# Derive $\tan(3x)$ in terms of $\tan(x)$ using De Moivre's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Derive the following identity: $$\tan(3x)=\frac{3\tan(x)-\tan^3(x)}{1-3\tan^2(x)}$$

The way I approached the questions is that I first derived $\sin(3x)$ and $\cos(3x)$ because $\tan(\theta)=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$. Then substituting:

$$\tan(3x)=\frac{\sin(3x)}{\cos(3x)}=\frac{-4\sin^3(x)+3\sin(x)}{4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)}$$

I transformed it into $$\tan(3x)=\frac{-4\sin^2(x)\tan(x)+3\tan(x)}{4\cos^2(x)-3}$$ and also to $$\tan(3x)=-\tan(x)\frac{4\sin^2(x)-3}{-4\sin^2(x)+1}$$ but I'm stuck on either of these forms. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't “normalize” the triplication formulas to only sines and cosines.

We have
$$
\cos3x+i\sin3x=\cos^3x+3i\cos^2x\sin x-3\cos x\sin^2x-i\sin^3x
$$
so
\begin{align}
\sin3x&=3\cos^2x\sin x-\sin^3x \\[6px]
\cos3x&=\cos^3x-3\cos x\sin^2x \\[12px]
\tan3x&=\frac{3\cos^2x\sin x-\sin^3x}{\cos^3x-3\cos x\sin^2x}
\end{align}

Now divide numerator and denominator by $\cos^3x$.

Answer (score 1):

Wthout de Moivre:

$$\tan(2x+x)=\frac{\tan2x+\tan x}{1-\tan2x\tan x}=\frac{\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}+\tan x}{1-\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}\tan x}=$$

$$=\frac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}=\tan x\frac{(\tan x-\sqrt3)(\tan x+\sqrt3)}{(\sqrt3\,\tan x-1)(\sqrt3\,\tan x+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{4\sin^2 x-3}{-4\sin^2 x +1}&=\frac{1-4\cos^2 x}{4\cos^2 x-3 }\\[5pt]
&=\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}-4}{4-\frac{3}{\cos^2x}},\qquad\text{for }\cos x\neq 0\\[5pt]
&=\frac{\sec^2 x-4}{4-3\sec^2 x}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{(\color{blue}{\tan^2 x+1})-4}{4-3(\color{blue}{\tan^2 x+1})}
\end{align*}

Then, the identity follows straightforward.